# Bulk editing Gmail filters

Tags: gmail-filters

I'm trying to edit my 400+ filters to ensure the filtered messages are `Never marked as Spam.` It appears to me that the only way to "bulk edit" Gmail filters is to edit the XML file.

Before I attempt that (and so far I've failed at my first attempt) is there another, easier way to do this?

Comment: I'm contemplating writing an app that will make bulk editing the XML easy, because the web interface is awful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. The only way to edit Gmail filters all at once is via a XML file.

Comment: On another note, you should be sparing with the 'Never marked as Spam.'. I've been getting a lot of phishing emails that come through (LinkedIn, Facebook, etc) as a result of my use of the 'Never mark as Spam' option.

Comment: Great point. The filters are starting to reset themselves (the right mail starting to make it through) ... I might just wait.

Comment: In fact, I'm pretty sure they added the export feature for just this purpose. It was only added in the last year or two. Before that you were truly out of luck.