# How to bulk edit filters in Gmail to migrate from one label to another?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email, gmail-labels, imap

How are labels merged so that filters are included as well?

So that `Alice` and `Bob` instead are directed to `Carol`, for example.  Crucially, any filters for `Alice` or `Bob` will now work with `Carol` instead.  Asked differently, how are the filters [merged or migrated](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/28162/204070)?

The three names:  `Alice`, `Bob` and `Carol` are `gmail` labels.  In an `IMAP` client, or through the web interface, it's easy enough to rename a directory or label.  *It's easy enough to copy, or move, e-mails from one label to another.*

However, how are the `filter`'s updated so that `Alice` and `Bob` no longer receive any e-mails at all?  **All mail which was being directed to `Alice` and `Bob` should now go directly to `Carol`.**

Again, the names:  `Alice`, `Bob` and `Carol` are just labels within `gmail` for illustrative purposes.  Through `IMAP` the labels are reflected as directories, of course.

Comment: Labels don't receive emails.  Emails are labelled.  By using that language in addition to using people's names as labels your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: Yes, labels receive e-mails in the sense that labels show as folders in IMAP and those folders certainly receive e-mails.  Alice is just label "A", and Bob is just label "B" is all.  Folders A,B and C receive e-mails from the standpoint of IMAP.

Comment: Misconstruing gmail-labels as 'folders' is understandable.  IMAP clients connected to Gmail may reinforce this belief.  Lack of understanding of the nature of gmail-labels is the core of many support posts here & elsewhere, & much frustration for experienced & green users alike.  To solve a problem with gmail-labels, disabuse yourself of the notion that 'labels' are a synonym for 'folders.'  My other point was to encourage you to write examples (use cases) using language that minimizes the potential for confusion & ambiguity.  Hope that clarifies.

Comment: The link you provided  (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/28162/204070) answers your question.  Bulk editing of gmail-filters is done via XML.  You export all your filters as XML, edit the file in a text editor, then import the updated XML file.